# C - Convert char to int

Tags: c, type-conversion

I know that to convert any given char to int, this code is possible [apart from atoi()]:

```
int i = '2' - '0';
```

but I never understood how it worked, what is significance of '0' and I don't seem to find any explanation on the net about that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: thanks for all replies, quite useful stuff :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, a character literal has type `int`. [[Character Literals/IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc02ccon.htm)]

In your example, the numeric value of `'0'` is 48, the numeric value of `'2'` is 50. When you do `'2' - '0'` you get `50 - 48 = 2`. This works for ASCII numbers from 0 to 9.

See [ASCII table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii%20table) to get a better picture.

**Edit:** Thanks to @ouah for correction.

Comment: So when I add or subtract any char type, I'am manipulating their ASCII codes ??

Comment: @Alex, Numeric value of '2' is 50, not 58.

Comment: @engheema: Yes and no. There is a fine difference between a being equal to 2, or being equal to '2' which is equal to 50. Depends on which "interpretation" of char you're looking at.

Comment: `'0'` is `int` not because of integer promotions but because the type of character literals is `int`.

Answer (score 3):

All the chars in C are represented with an integer value, the ASCII code of the character.
For instance '0' corresponds to 48 and '2' corresponds to 50, so `'2'-'0'` gets you `50-48 = 2`

Link to an ASCII table: http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use the commas `' '` you are treating the number as a char, and if this is given to an int, the int will take the value of the ASCII code of this character.

Answer (score 2):

Any character literal enclosed in single quotes corresponds to a number that represents the ASCII code of that character. In fact, such literals evaluate not to `char`, but to `int`, so they are perfectly interchangeable with other number literals.

Within your expression, `'2'` is interchangeable with `50`, and `'0'` is interchangeable with `48`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ASCII table.

`'0'` is represented as 0x30, `'9'` is represented as 0x32.

This results in

```
0x32 - 0x30 = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the corresponding characters.

In C, all the digits (0 to 9) are encoded in ASCII by values 48 to 57, sequentially. So `'0'` actually gets value 48, and `'2'` has the value 50. So when you write `int i = '2' - '0';`, you're actually subtracting 48 from 50, and get 2.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be sequential values in C in all character sets. This not limited to ASCII and C is not limited to the ASCII character set.

So sequential here means that `'2'` value  is `'0' + 2`.

Regarding `int` and `char` note that `'0'` and `'9'` values are of type `int` in C and not of type `char`. A character literal is of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Both terms are internally represented by the ASCII code of the number, and as numeric digits have consecutive ASCII codes subtracting them gives you the difference between the two numbers.

You can do similar tricks with characters as well, eg shift lowercase to uppercase by subtracting 32 from a lowercase character

```
'a' - 32 = 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

This works only because ASCII assigns codes to characters in order i.e. '2' has a character code that is with 2 bigger than the character code of '0'.

In an another encoding it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast a char to an int it actually maps each character to the appropriate number in the ascii table.

This means that `'2' - '0'` is translated to `50 - 48`.
So you could also find out the numeric distance of two letters in the same way, e.g.
`'z' - 'a'` equals `122 - 97` equals `25`

You can look up the numeric representaions of each ASCII character in thsi table:
http://www.asciitable.com/

Actually a `char` is just a unsigned byte: C just treats it differently for different operations. For example `printf(97)` yields `97` as output, but `printf((char)97)` will give you `'a'` as output.