# Convert a char array of 0 and 1 to bytes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, byte

I have a question here. It might sound trivial to you but not for me since I'm pretty much still a noob in C++. (also sorry for my limited english knowledge)

Let's say I have a `char a[72]` array. This array is filled with `'0'` and `'1'` representing bits (`a[0] = '0'`, `a[1] = '1'`, `a[2] = '1'` etc.) and I need to save this as a binary file, so when I try to view this file with **xxd -b** i would like to see these 9 bytes as they were in the array.

Could please anybody lead me to the solution how to convert this char array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - Convert char to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432986/c-convert-char-to-int)

Comment: Just out of interest: Do you have special reason, not to use `std::bitset` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your array in groups of 8 symbols and convert each group from binary string representation to unsigned char. For example:

```
unsigned char byte = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
    if( a[i] == '1' ) byte |= 1 << (7-i);
```

Then put that bytes into another array size 72/8 and store it into file, for example by `std::ostream::write()` method. You may group bits by 16, 32 or 64 bits and use `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` for values, but this way is most simple and you probably should start with it and make it work first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've used your code for a small fragment of my code and it does what I've wanted it to do so far. Thank you again.

Comment: @Keygori , don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer ( the tick mark right next to the answer ) if the answer has helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
const std::size_t n = 72;
std::vector<char> byteArray(n / 8);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n / 8; ++i)
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        if (a[i * 8 + j] == '1')
            byteArray[i] |= 1 << j;
```

Then access `byteArray` with `operator[]()` or `data()`.